# Sitecore: Get Media Item from master database

Tags: sitecore

```
hyperlink.NavigateUrl = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/',Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item));
```

When I am trying to click on link, it says resource not found. because it is trying to get the item from web database. How can I get the item from master database?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it by code. Please refer to [Sitecore fundamentals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342755/what-is-the-difference-between-sitecores-core-master-and-web-databases)

You should either publish item. 
Or switch you website to use master database instead of web:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="website">
        <patch:attribute name="database">master</patch:attribute>
      </site>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of the line: *?sc_database=master*

It should now look like:

`hyperlink.NavigateUrl = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/',Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item)) + "?sc_database=master";`

Answer (score 0):

While I agree completely with @Anton's answer, to answer your specific question:

> how i can get the item from master database

Here's how you would do that:

```
var masterDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

var itemFromMaster = masterDB.GetItem(item.ID);
```

Comment: Although you *can* do that, OP should consider if he *should*. If this is public-facing website code and the site is deployed to a CD server, best practice for CD servers is to remove the connectionstring for "master". If that is done, both of these answers will fail.